# How to use XCTestSuite using Swift 4/Xcode 10?

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, swift4.2

I'm trying to make parameterized tests in Xcode using `XCTestSuite` (instead of using other libraries such as [Quick](https://quick.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).

I've created a XCTestSuite subclass:

```
final class IDDocParametrizedTest: XCTestSuite {

override class var `default`: XCTestSuite {

    let testSuite = XCTestSuite(name: "TestSuite")

    let fixtures = ["Form8", "Form_example"]

    for fixture in fixtures {
        let testCases = IDDocTest.createTestCases()
        for testCase in testCases {
            testCase.fixture = fixture
            testSuite.addTest(testCase)
        }
    }
    return testSuite
}
}
```

and my `XCTestCase` subclass is something like this:

```
final class IDSDocumentTest: XCTestCase {

    class func createTestCases() -> [IDSDocumentTest] {
        return self.testInvocations.map { IDSDocumentTest(invocation: $0) }
    }

    var fixture = ""

    func testCover() { ... }
    func testCancelCover() { ... }
}
```

If I've understood well, Xcode uses a default `XCTestSuite` and runs my tests with `fixture`== "". Instead, I would like Xcode to use my `IDDocParametrizedTest` and then runs a suite of parameterized tests.

Did I get it right?
How can I say to Xcode to use my `IDDocParametrizedTest` instead of its default `XCTestSuite`?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find how to do it?

Comment: @Lucas no, I'm using Quick :-/